Enable shadows only for part of the object
Context
I'm trying to reproduce the kind of shaders we've seen in Project Gold, Puss In Boots 2, Spiderverse, ... based on brush strokes. I have a very simple basis with geometry nodes.
I know Blender Studio has released the extension they mainly used for Project Gold. I'm trying to do the same kind of shader for myself.
I have a set of brushes, which are planes with textures I made :

I generate instances of these brushes on the object surface with geometry nodes. For now, I have the following result, for a cube :

Issue
My problem is, I'd like the base object (cube) to cast shadows. But I don't want the brushes to cast shadows, especially on the base object it belongs to. This problem is highlighted on the next image with "not ok" label, the black spots on the cube.
How can I only enable shadows for the base object, if both the base object and the brush strokes are inside the same object ?

Conditions
Here is a list of the conditions I'd like to satisfy. If you think one of these is irrelevant or would prevent me to achieve the effect, let me know !

The effect shouldn't depend on render layers, I want it to be shader-only. Of course I could render the strokes on a separate layer and use compositing.
The brush strokes should be inside the same object as the base object it is applied to. I don't want to have to create a child object for every object in the scene.
The object have to cast shadows.
The strokes shouldn't cast shadows on their base object.
The strokes may cast shadows on the scene if there is no other way.
The strokes should stay as instances and not realized geometry, for performance sake.

To summarize, I'd like it to be shader-only, geometry-nodes-only and the brushes should be created in the base object, not as a separate object.
Is there any way to achieve that ? Am I missing some obvious settings ? Thank you for time :)

Could you add some images of the shaders you are talking about that would be the desired result? It's hard to understand what exactly you are talking about from 3 names of movies. I mean they have many scenes with many shaders and many types of shadows...

Nothing special for the shader, just diffuse with transparency. I'll add it. The shaders I mentionned don't matter, I just want the brush instances not to cast shadows on their base object.

OK, so why not just do it in the shader the most obvious way?

Because I'm bad at Blender ? Ahah I think you just answer my question, I'll take a look.

I am not sure I understand the situation completely, but sure, you can use Light Paths node's Is Shadow Ray. If you wanted only some objects to receive the shadows that might get awkward with various tricks that might not be that elegant.  There is also Transparent and Transmission Depth and it's possible to then use all sorts of transparent objects to mask stuff in the scene. That's a bit messy though - like here the lower monkey has duplicate geometry on top of it with transparent shader so it doesn't receive shadows of the higher one.

It might be possible to do these things with light linking, but I have never used that, so no idea how it works, if we are talking about being bad at Blender ;)

You solved my issue, thank you :) I'll wait a few days if you want to write a short answer, otherwise I'll write one for posterity.

I think it would be awesome if you found the time to put it into understandable manner for someone with similar problem. Sorry for not having the patience of writing an official answer.
